# Why there is a difference between sp_helpfile vs sys.master_files?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, system-tables

Hi while restoring database using restore command in sql server to specific drive, after executing `sp_helpfile` its showing incorrect file path, however `sys.master_files` showing right file path ?
why `sp_helpfile` showing inaccurate path? can somebody please help me to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long to comment.

I suspect you aren't connected to the correct database when you run `sp_helpfile`. If you query `sys.master_files` it will return the same thing regardless of what database you are connected to. However, sp_helpfile used the default connection if you don't specify a file name. Thus, if you are connected to `[master]` it will return results for the files of this database.

Comment: I'd agree.  Compare the output of `exec sp_helpfile` and `select * from sys.master_files where database_id = db_id()` run in the same context, and the path should always match..

Comment: but in my case it doesn't they are showing different path

Comment: What's the results from both queries for you @VikrantMore

Comment: sp_helpfile showing me the path of what i set while restoring database manually, however sys.master_files showing the path after restoring database from restore command

Comment: so you are restoring `with move`?

Comment: yes, using this command, RESTORE DATABASE <DBName> FROM DISK = <DBFilePath> WITH STATS = 10 , MOVE 'PrimaryFileName' TO 'H:\DBName.mdf',MOVE 'PrimaryLogFileName' TO 'J:\DBName.ldf';

Comment: is it the PATH that is wrong or the NAME? It sounds like you are mixing logical and physical file names. This would be relevant in the difference from the name column and the physical_name column in sys.master_files

Comment: Path & Name both are correct, but still the file location should be physical not logical since it should be physically exists at that file path

Answer (score 1):

Using `exec sp_helptext N'sp_helpfile'` brings up the definition for `sp_helpfile`.

This shows that it is using `sys.sysfiles`, which is an old 2000-era system view, which is now for compatibility only. Just one more reason not to use the horrible `sp_help` procedures.

Comparing the definition for `sys.sysfiles` and `sys.database_files` shows tha both use the internal system table or view `sys.sysprufiles`. The only primary difference is that `sysfiles` uses the filter:

```sql
WHERE filetype IN (0, 1) -- x_eft_SQLData, x_eft_SQLLog (bwkcmpt types)
  AND filestate NOT IN (1, 2, 3) -- x_efs_Dummy, x_efs_Dropped, x_efs_DroppedReusePending
```

whereas `database_files` uses only

```sql
WHERE filestate NOT IN (1, 2)   -- x_efs_Dummy, x_efs_Dropped
```

On the other hand, you are comparing with `sys.master_files`, which is a global view, uses a different system table `sys.sysbrickfiles`. It has the following filters:

```sql
WHERE f.dbid < 0x7fff -- consistent with sys.databases
  AND f.pruid = 0
  AND f.filestate NOT IN (1, 2) -- x_efs_Dummy, x_efs_Dropped
```

Neither of these are in the list of [base tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), so either they are undocumented, or they are views to other base tables.

Exactly what the difference between them is is unclear, but `master_files` is global across the server, so it's possible taht its source is not being updated correctly, or is a little behind on updates.

Answer (score 0):

sp_helpfile output comes from the database,
sys.master_files is the file physical location.
When you restore a database before recovery, sp_helpfile get the file location from the backup which shows the file location at the time the backup was made.
After restore and recovery, the file location in database will be changed to the physical location as the one in sys.master_file